# EF Code First Custom Collections

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

When creating code first collections can you implement a custom class that implements ICollection. The code below is conceptual not actual

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //Want to Avoid This
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    //Use his instead of above
    public ProductList ProductsInCategory {get;set;}
}
public class ProductsList :ICollection<Product>
{
   public int DiscontinuedProductsCount
   {
        return internalList.Count();
   }
    //Icollection Methods Excluded
}
```

Answer (score 7):

EF can indeed support any collection which inherits from ICollection. We create a deletable collection to support auto deletions and also create collections for child objects to keep the size of our main object smaller.

Comment: Theres also a big gotcha. The collection you create must have a default empty constructor. We were trying to pass in an Id to the constructor and this went very badly. I hate that ICollection exposes Add(). It totally restricts DDD design.

Comment: You can make the ICollection property mapped to EF internal and expose a public adapter that adds custom behavior and doesn't provide Add().