# Validate entities when adding to a navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation, collections

I have an entity with a collection property that looks something like this:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public virtual ICollection<OtherEntity> Others { get; set; }
}
```

When I retrieve this entity via the data context or repository, I want to prevent others adding items to this collection through the use of `MyEntity.Others.Add(entity)`. This is because I may want some validation code to be performed before adding my entity to the collection. I'd do this by providing a method on `MyEntity` like this:

```
public void AddOther(OtherEntity other)
{
    // perform validation code here

    this.Others.Add(other);
}
```

I've tested a few things so far, and what I've eventually arrived at is something like this.  I create a `private` collection on my entity and expose a `public ReadOnlyCollection<T>` so `MyEntity` looks like this:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    private readonly ICollection<OtherEntity> _others = new Collection<OtherEntity>();

    public virtual IEnumerable<OtherEntity>
    {
        get
        {
            return _others.AsEnumerable();
        }
    }
}
```

This **seems** to be what I'm looking for and my unit tests pass fine, but I haven't yet started to do any integration testing so I'm wondering:

1. Is there a better way to achieve what I'm looking for?
2. What are the implications I'll face if I decide to go down this route (if feasible)?

Thanks always for any and all help.

**Edit 1** I've changed from using a `ReadOnlyCollection` to `IEnumerable` and am using `return _others.AsEnumerable();` as my getter. Again unit tests pass fine, but I'm unsure of the problems I'll face during integration and EF starts building these collections with related entities.

**Edit 2** So, I decided to try out suggestions of creating a derived collection (call it `ValidatableCollection`) implementing `ICollection` where my `.Add()` method would perform validation on the entity provided before adding it to the internal collection. Unfortunately, Entity Framework invokes this method when building the navigation property - so it's not really suitable.

Comment: what .net version do you use?

Comment: @IlyaIvanov My project is MVC3 so I'm using .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally have a suitable working solution, here's what I did. I'll change `MyEntity` and `OtherEntity` to something more readable, like `Teacher` and `Student` where I want to stop a teacher teaching more students than they can handle.

First, I created an interface for all entities that I intend to validate in this way called `IValidatableEntity` that looks like this:

```
public interface IValidatableEntity
{
    void Validate();
}
```

Then I implement this interface on my `Student` because I'm validating this entity when adding to the collection of `Teacher`.

```
public class Student : IValidatableEntity
{
    public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }

    public void Validate()
    {
        if (this.Teacher.Students.Count() > this.Teacher.MaxStudents)
        {
            throw new CustomException("Too many students!");
        }
    }
}
```

Now onto how I invoke validate. I override `.SaveChanges()` on my entity context to get a list of all entities added and for each invoke validate - if it fails I simply set its state to detached to prevent it being added to the collection. Because I'm using exceptions (something I'm still unsure of at this point) as my error messages, I `throw` them out to preserve the stack trace.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
    {
        if (entry.State == System.Data.EntityState.Added)
        {
            if (entry.Entity is IValidatableEntity)
            {
                try
                {
                    (entry.Entity as IValidatableEntity).Validate();
                }
                catch
                {
                    entry.State = System.Data.EntityState.Detached;

                    throw; // preserve the stack trace
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

This means I keep my validation code nicely tucked away within my entity which will make my life a whole lot easier when mocking my POCOs during unit testing.

Answer (score 2):

I would create collection class exactly for this purpose:

```
OtherEntityCollection : Collection<OtherEntity>
{
    protected override void InsertItem(int index, OtherEntity item)
    {
        // do your validation here
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }

    // other overrides
}
```

This will make much more rigid, because there will be no way to bypass this validation. You can check more complex example in [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132412.aspx).

One thing I'm not sure is how to make EF create this concrete type when it materializes data from database. But it is probably doable as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445522/ef-code-first-custom-collections).

**Edit:**
If you want to keep the validation inside the entity, you could make it generic through custom interface, that the entity would implement and your generic collection, that would call this interface.

As for problems with EF, I think the biggest problem would be that when EF rematerializes the collection, it calls `Add` for each item. This then calls the validation, even when the item is not "added" as business rule, but as an infrastructure behavior. This might result in weird behavior and bugs.

Comment: I was thinking about this, but what put me off is a) I'd like to avoid having to create one derived collection for each entity, which has specific validation, and keep this code inside the entity definition and b) how would having a derived collection affect the proxy generation for the collection that EF does?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest returning to `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`. I've used it in [similar scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443144/resticting-access-to-method-calls-on-read-only-properties) in the past, and I've had no problems.

Additionally, the `AsEnumerable()` approach will not work, as it only changes the type of the reference, it does not generate a new, independent object, which means that this

```
MyEntity m = new MyEntity();
Console.WriteLine(m.Others.Count()); //0
(m.Others as Collection<OtherEntity>).Add(new OtherEntity{ID = 1});
Console.WriteLine(m.Others.Count()); //1
```

will successfully insert in your private collection.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `AsEnumerable()` on `HashSet`, because collection can be easily modified by casting it to `ICollection<OtherEntity>`

```
var values = new MyEntity().Entities;
((ICollection<OtherEntity>)values).Add(new OtherEntity());
```

Try to return copy of a list like

```
return new ReadOnlyCollection<OtherEntity>(_others.ToList()).AsEnumerable();
```

this makes sure that users will recieve exception if they will try to modify it. You can expose `ReadOnlyCollection` as return type enstead of `IEnumerable` for clarity and convenience of users. In .NET 4.5 a new interface was added `IReadOnlyCollection`.

You won't have big integration issues except some component depend on List mutation. If users will call ToList or ToArray, they will return a copy

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here:

1) The way you are currently using: expose the collection as a `ReadOnlyCollection<OtherEntity>` and add methods in the `MyEntity` class to modify that collection. This is perfectly fine, but take into account that you are adding the validation logic for a collection of `OtherEntity` in a class that just *uses* that collection, so if you use collections of `OtherEntity` elsewhere in the project, you will need probably need to *replicate* the validation code, and that's a code smell (DRY) :P

2) To solve that, the best way is to create a custom `OtherEntityCollection` class implementing `ICollection<OtherEntity>` so you can add the validation logic there. It's really simple because you can create a simple OtherEntityCollection object that contains a `List<OtherEntity>` instance which really implements the collection operations, so you just need to validate the insertions:.

Edit: If you need custom validation for multiple entities you should create a custom collection which receives some other object that perform that validation. I've modified the example below, but it shouldn't be difficult to create a generic class:

```
class OtherEntityCollection : ICollection<OtherEntity>  
{
  OtherEntityCollection(Predicate<OtherEntity> validation)
  {
    _validator = validator;
  } 

  private List<OtherEntity> _list = new List<OtherEntity>();
  private Predicate<OtherEntity> _validator;
  public override void Add(OtherEntity entity)   
  {
     // Validation logic
     if(_validator(entity))
       _list.Add(entity);   
  }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about this, but what put me off is a) I'd like to avoid having to create one derived collection for each entity, which has specific validation, and keep this code inside the entity definition and b) how would having a derived collection affect the proxy generation for the collection that EF does?

Comment: Then you could extract the validation code outside the collection class. See my edits and tell me what you think

Comment: This is looking more like it, currently having a play with this.

Comment: I've used a simple predicate validator to simplify but you could use a custom object if validation logic is complex.

Answer (score 0):

EF can't map property without setter. or even `private set { }` requires some configuration. keep models as POCO, Plain-Old like DTO

the common approach is to create separated service layer that contain validation logic against your Model before save.

for sample..

```
public void AddOtherToMyEntity(MyEntity myEntity, OtherEntity otherEntity)
{
    if(myService.Validate(otherEntity)
    {
      myEntity.Others.Add(otherEntity);
    }
    //else ...
}
```

ps. You could prevent compiler to do somethings but not other coders. Just made your code explicitly says "don't modify Entity Collection directly, until it passed validation"